# How to hide/move image while writting

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writting a form on Flutter but while I'm writting, the textFields doesn't see because the keyboard cover it. So, I want to reduce the size of the image and move if necessary to show the textfiels.

This is how it starts:

[image]

And when I'm writting on password field this is how it is:

[image]

So, i want that when I'm writting the page move to see the active focus textfield. Each TextField has a TextController and a FocusNode but i don't know how to solve it.

One example of a textField:

```
final emailField = TextFormField(
      controller: emailController,
      focusNode: emailFocusNode,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocusNode);
      },
      validator: (val) =>
          (!EmailValidator.validate(val)) ? 'Incorrect Email' : null,
      onSaved: (val) => _username = val,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Email",
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          filled: true,
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );
```

Summarizing, I need to move the screen depending on what TextField is selected to show it and that it isn't covered by the keyboard.

Comment: You can wrap it into a ScrollerView. when you will textfields wil be focussed, the image will sccoll to the top

Comment: @user8773560 could you expose an example pls?

Comment: Are you using `Scaffold` for this Screen? Also, use `ListView` instead of `Column` for your TextFileds and Images, then you should be fine. What will help you here is a property in Scaffold i.e. `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` which defaults to `true`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html

Comment: @JuanGomez Provide the code for your entire screen for us to help you out, if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include your code inside **SingleChildScrollView** for example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class S56887705 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailField = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 25.0, 20.0, 25.0),
          hintText: "Email",
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          filled: true,
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              emailField,
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a GestureDetector and i forgot SingleChildScrollView